# problems with - Facebook Like Button Admin access

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've been having trouble accessing admin privledges for the like buttons on my website (along with other things).

This is the situation:

1. I have made a facebook page for my website www.digitaldemocracy.org.uk
2. I have made a facebook app for my website that allows people with facebook accounts to register and login to the site. This works fine.
3. Like buttons are associated with different php dynamically created pages on my website i.e. www.digitaldemocracy.org.uk/debate/debate.php?id=3850. These Like buttons work when users click on them. I also have a like button for the main page www.digitaldemocracy.org.uk which works a bit funny as it seems to sum up all the likes from the other pages (even though they all have different URLs associated with them)

Now what I'm having issues with:

1. I have put 3 facebook UIDs into the metatags for admin purposes for the Like buttons. I have tested some links with the fb Linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/)  and it doesn't seem to have any issues, but when I click the like buttons myself, I get no admin features. I have also tried accessing admin priv directly from facebook, but no luck with that either.
2. I read that you can tie admin rights to a fb page, so then I tried it with the facebook page (page_id) for the site, but no luck with that either.
3. I then tried to give admin rights from my website to the facebook app, but when i test it with the linter it says that i have associate it with the specific page www.digitaldemocracy.org.uk/debate/debate.php?id=unique_id, which seems to defeat the purpose of what i'm trying to do (tie all the website pages together so i can easily administrate them).
4. The furthest I've got is to see the insights for the domain www.digitaldemocracy.org.uk/ (where i wasn't able to before), but I can't seem to see likes for individual pages and I don't seem to have any admin rights about publishing to user's feed or seeing who the 'likers' are! Am I missing something now?

It 'seems' to be that i'm doing all the correct things specified by the documentation, but I have getting nowhere and don't know what else to do. I have searched forums for answers, but they're just all over the place. I hope that stating my exact problem and what I've done will hopefully find someone able to help me!

Thanks in advance.

Denise

Comment: Post your code for the like button please

Answer (score 1):

2 things I have found:

1. It seems the Admin link will only appear when you are using the default like button settings (ie faces on etc)
2. For the times that I could not get the Admin link to appear, I ran the linter and it suddenly did.

Perhaps try emptying the cache for your browser too but I have a feeling the first point might solve your problem?

I could be wrong, would love to hear someone else's opinion!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been driving me crazy ever since I accidentally discovered that these magical pages existed. I've had them show up with and without appIds in the fb js snippet. There doesn't seem to be any logic.

Item 1 from Sam Hammond doesn't seem to matter. Most of my Like buttons have data-show-faces set to false.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mysite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

From the above example I have seen the following:

- Actual Web Page Like Button shows "9k"
- My admin page shows "1.7k"

It's great. I can reach 1.7k people who Liked the page. But what about the rest and what about any new pages I create?

For now, when in doubt, drop the Facebook Page Like Box on your web page because at least it works consistently:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

I also have to wonder how facebook users react when they start seeing posts in their feed from sites they Liked. It seems a bit intrusive.

I frequently use the Linter/Debugger tool on my web pages, doesn't seem to make anything appear. But this tool is highly recommended for other purposes:
updated link from above is: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug